# How to change moving location icon using google maps in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

[image]

please help me I am new in the flutter

```
GoogleMap(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: mapBottomPadding,
              ),
              initialCameraPosition: _kGoogle,
              mapToolbarEnabled: true,
              buildingsEnabled: true,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              mapType: MapType.terrain,
              markers: markers,
              trafficEnabled: true,
              // on below line setting compass enabled.
              compassEnabled: true,
              onMapCreated: onMapcreated,
              zoomControlsEnabled: true,
            ),
```

i also shared my google maps code

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this code snippet for google maps change moving location iconhttps://gist.github.com/samuchakraborty/243842a1a93956e64dc8781d0f9fb313